# How to use number as Variable in following code?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am very new to SML-NJ. I am writing a code to add the values of Number1 and Number2 in SML-NJ. I want to use the  GRAAL like data type definition in my code.

Part - A :

```
type Variable=string
type Integer_constant=int
```

I want to do something like following.

```
val number = Variable
```

Part - B :
I know that if I have used the datatype as Variable then it is going to work,
Working case as below,

```
datatype Variable=str of string
type Integer_constant=int
val number = str("number");
```

Now, I have to do the same thing in a Part - A which is present in Part-B.
Indirectly, I have to used type as a data definition for the Variable.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. I have read it several times and still don't know what you are asking. Perhaps by `val number = Variable` you are trying to do something like `val number = "42": Variable`?

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your quick response. Yes, I am looking for the same thing which you have mention in your comment. I got my code working. Thanks a lot once again.